# Unable to connect to socket.io using express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create WebSocket using the following code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = new http.createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

const CONFIG = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    const sid = socket.id

    console.log('connection socket id:', sid)

    for (const msg of ['disconnect', 'disconnecting', 'error']) {
        socket.on(msg, data => {
            console.log(`* ${msg}:`, data)
        })
    }

    socket.on('join', data => {
        console.console.log("data", data)
    })

    socket.on('signal', data => {
        console.log('signal', data)
    })
})

server.listen({
    host: CONFIG.host,
    port: CONFIG.port,
}, info => {
    console.info(`Running on`, server.address())
})
```

When I try to test this using `https://www.websocket.org/echo.html` I'm receiving an undefined error.

I have given `ws://127.0.0.1:4444` in the location field but when I try to connect I'm getting the following error in the Log:

```
ERROR: undefined
```

and in the message `Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

What is wrong here how I can make this working?

Comment: @TamasSzoke - getting `TypeError: server.listeners is not a function` from `node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js`

Comment: Could you add the client side code?

Comment: @TamasSzoke -  I was testing using `https://www.websocket.org/echo.html`. It should be fine for testing right?

Comment: Oh, I think that could be the problem, you should try it like in the example in the [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) docs.

Comment: @TamasSzoke - yes that was the problem, thanks for the help!

Comment: You cannot connect a webSocket client to a socket.io server.  That was your original problem.  You have to connect a socket.io client to a socket.io server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server seems good, you should implement the client yourself.

Socket.IO server and client example from the [documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Client (index.html):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    socket.emit('message', 'Test message.');
  });
</script>
```